# Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Time limit reached)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, codespaces

I ran into this issue frequently today, and I had to resort to a workaround, but it will happen again soon.

> Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Time limit reached)

Screenshot:
[image: Failed to connect to vs codespaces]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you figure out a solution to this? i created a self host wsl but this is what i keep getting.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue